# How do we remind people not to feed the trolls?

Tags: discussion

We have a lazy spammer sending a couple copies of the same essay (rockets are real) in per day.  During this time some users comment, say not to do this, etc.

Having lived a lifetime on the internet, I can say that this attention is what the spammer wants.  They want to argue, they want to call people names and be annoying.  The point is not the stupid essay they know will be deleted in a day or so.  The point is annoying us.

However, it also doesn't seem practical to go into the comments of each of these spam answers, @-mention each of the actual users who are engaging with the spammer so that they'll even notice, and ask them not to interact.  It makes even less sense since that would be also notify the spammer, giving them attention and an opportunity to interact and be annoying.

What more can we do as a community / can I do as a user to discourage feeding the trolls?  Isn't the optimum strategy to just downvote, flag, vote to delete, and move on?

Comment: NOTE:Some of it just say "SPAM" over and over again. And the rockets are real essays vary with the same idea. My guess is they are GPT generated. Anyway, I guess they are trying to get a diversity of nonsense.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch maybe I haven't looked at all of them, but out of 7 "rockets are real essays" I've found, the only difference that the standard GNU diff tools report is that a couple begin with "Here is why I think **that** rockets are real" and most omit the "that."  One had a long hex string up front.  The nonsense doesn't seem all that diverse tbh.